# Visual web developer 2010 express autocomplete not working

Tags: visual-studio-2010, autocomplete

I'm working with Visual Web Developer 2010 Express. I tend to bump at very strange problem.

Somehow, the autocomplete function gets disabled out of nowhere in the editor, and i have no idea how to bring it back on again. There are no errors, no warnings (a javascript file).

It seems that it turns off whenever i get close to a code fragment which has a link in it (ex. var sLink = "http://www.google.com/"). This link is sure highlighted in blue and underlined.

I don't understand what is going on. Whats wrong with it. When i reload the Visual developer, i **CAN** use the autocomplete functionality, but only **ONCE**, in the function containing the link.

After that, nothing is done, i start writing the name of variable and no box is popin up with a list. I can go to another function which has no links in it, and it works!

I am really confused. Help would be appreciated. It's really hard to work without autocomplete.

Answer (score 0):

Autocomplete works based on it's ability to parse the entire javascript file (or relevant parts of it). If there is some javascript error or invalid syntax in that function, then it will fail to autocomplete there.

Try creating a shell function, and then add the lines from the problematic function by one until you find the individual line that causes the problem. Then temporarily comment out that line while you complete the function.